# Compare alternatively recursively an element in a list

Tags: ocaml

I want to compare for instance: 
I have a list `l: [11,2,2,3]`
let `x = 11, y = 2, z = 2 and t = 3`.
I want to compare `x to y, z, t` and then compare `y to z, t` and then `z to t.` 
If they are equals then put them into a list, otherwise continue to compare the rest of the list.
This is what I have done so far, but it does not give me the correct answer. The result I am expecting is the list: `[y, z] => [2,2]` Could you please help me? Thank you.

```
let rec compare_element_list l =
    match l with
    | [] | [_] -> []
    | x :: y :: [] ->
      if x = y
      then
        (*add x and y into a list*)
        let result = x :: y :: [] in
        result
      else
        []
    | x :: y :: tl ->
      if x = y
      then
        let result = x :: y :: [] in
        result; compare_element_list tl
      else
        match tl with
        | [] -> []
        | [z] ->
          if x = z then
            let result = x :: z :: [] in result
          else []
        | z :: tl' ->
          if x = z
          then
            let result = x :: z :: [] in
            result; compare_element_list tl'
          else compare_element_list tl'
```

Comment: It's hard to help without a more careful problem statement, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each element of your list, you only need to check whether it's a member of the rest of the list. You get the following function:

```
let rec compare_element_list = function
  | [] | [_] -> []
  | x::tail ->
    let result = compare_element_list tail in
    if List.mem x tail
    then x::x::result
    else result
```

This function above is not tail-recursive however. Here is the tail-recursive version:

```
let rec compare_element_list buf = function
  | [] | [_] -> buf
  | x::tail ->
    if List.mem x tail
    then compare_element_list (x::x::buf) tail
    else compare_element_list buf tail
```

(To apply the tail-rec version, you need to provide an empty buffer:
 `compare_element_list [] [11;2;2;3]` )